# How to maintain the escaped quotes in an expression in Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

When I configure my stream to be depoyed, in which I'm using a processor (transform, script or http-request), in the "expression" atribute I need to set an expression that contains quotes and double quotes (escaped). The expression works properly the first time I set and allows to deploy the stream, but if I undeploy the stream and try again to deploy it, the spring cloud data flow throws state machine exception because the backslashes used to escape the double quotes are removed.

I already follow the considerations in the Spaces and Quotes documentation, but I think that it only applies to the streams definition and not to the deployment time.

The URL of the spaces and quotes documentarion is: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#shell-white-space

And the sample of the type of expression required:

`expression="new String('{\"size\": 1,\"sort\": {\"timestamp\": \"desc\"},\"query\": {\"prefix\": {\"integrationname\": \"63320e0d313862934667225f\"}}}')"`

The stream could be as simple as:

`http | transform | log`

The firs time the expression is set looks like as follows:

`expression="new String('{\"size\": 1,\"sort\": {\"timestamp\": \"desc\"},\"query\": {\"prefix\": {\"integrationname\": \"63320e0d313862934667225f\"}}}')"`

Deploying correctly the stream.

Once the stream is undeployed and try to deploy it again, the espression looks like:

`expression="new String('{"size": 1,"sort\": {"timestamp": "desc"},"query": {"prefix": {"integrationname": "63320e0d313862934667225f"}}}')"`

Where the backslashes were removed, causing the state machine exception because of the unescaped double quotes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We are looking at [Issue #5145](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/5145) and will update the issue when we have fixed it.

In the meantime I would suggest using the spring-cloud-dataflow-shell or the REST API to automate deployments where you provide the properties every time as needed.